# What does isAjax always return false in this ASP.NET Core AJAX application?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement AJAX in ASP.NET Core so I have created a new default "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) with "Individual User Accounts".

I added `"Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax": "3.2.3"` at project.json under "dependencies" section.

for "Register.cshtml" I have changed the `<form>` declaration to

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

at "Register" action in AccountController I have changed it to check if the post is using AJAX.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var isAjax = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                // Send an email with this link
                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                //    $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The problem is that `isAjax` always returns `false`.

Comment: Before wondering why isAjax is always false you should start by checking if you really have the header "X-Requested-With" in your request. I'm sure you don't

Comment: Adding Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax in your project.json just adds a reference to this package in your project but it doesn't mean you are using it. You should learn how to properly use this library. Otherwise if you really want to send your HTTP request in AJAX (which I don't understand the reason), try in pure JavaScript or using jQuery (different than Unobtrusive.Ajax)

Answer (score 2):

I have added "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive": "3.2.4" thru bower.json and then a reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and now it is working.
Thanks @jerome for your help